# How to align radio buttons horizontally below labels

Tags: html, css, radio-button, alignment

So I am using the following HTML to display 4 radio buttons horizontally centered underneath their respective labels in a jsp:

```
<s:form action="markUser" name="markUser" method="post" namespace="/secure/admin">
    <div id="radioGroup">

        <label for="markStudent">Mark User as Student</label>
        <input type="radio" name="mark" id="markStudent" value="Student" />

        <label for="markAdmin">Mark User as Admin</label>
        <input type="radio" name="mark" id="markAdmin" value="Admin" />

        <label for="markService">Mark User as Service</label>
        <input type="radio" name="mark" id="markService" value="Service" />

        <label for="markNull">Mark User as Null</label>
        <input type="radio" name="mark" id="markNull" value="Null" />

    </div>
</s:form>
```

And CSS:

```
.radioGroup label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0.2em;
}
.radioGroup label input[type="radio"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
}
```

But I keep getting misaligned buttons like the following

[image: It wont go horizontal:/]

What might I be missing here?

Comment: You want the radio button to the right of the text?

Comment: Do you want all labels horizontal and each radio button below each label?

Comment: No, aligned horizontally with the buttons centered right below each corresponding label

Comment: I tried removing the label, and same result:/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it you want this

```css
#radioGroup .wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
#radioGroup label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0.2em;
}
#radioGroup input[type="radio"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="radioGroup">
  <div class="wrap">
    <label for="markStudent">Mark User as Student</label>
    <input type="radio" name="mark" id="markStudent" value="Student" />
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <label for="markAdmin">Mark User as Admin</label>
    <input type="radio" name="mark" id="markAdmin" value="Admin" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <label for="markService">Mark User as Service</label>
    <input type="radio" name="mark" id="markService" value="Service" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <label for="markNull">Mark User as Null</label>
    <input type="radio" name="mark" id="markNull" value="Null" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:**

This is incorrect on two fronts:

```
.radioGroup label input[type="radio"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
}
```

Firstly, the element has an ID of `radioGroup` not class

Secondly, the input is not a **child** of the label but rather a *sibling*

Answer (score 0):

You can put the radio buttons inside the labels and change up the CSS just a bit.

```css
.radioGroup label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
}
.radioGroup label input[type="radio"] {
  margin: 0.5em auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioGroup">
        <label for="markStudent">Mark User as Student<br />
            <input type="radio" name="mark" id="markStudent" value="Student" />
        </label>
        <label for="markAdmin">Mark User as Admin<br />
            <input type="radio" name="mark" id="markAdmin" value="Admin" />
        </label>
        <label for="markService">Mark User as Service<br />
            <input type="radio" name="mark" id="markService" value="Service" />
        </label>
        <label for="markNull">Mark User as Null<br />
            <input type="radio" name="mark" id="markNull" value="Null" />
        </label>
    </div>
```

This ensures that the radio buttons will be horizontally centered directly under their respective labels.