# evenly spaced, horizontal radio buttons with labels underneath

Tags: css, django, otree

For a user form I need several likert items. (Questions to assess the degree of an opinion. Example at the bottom)
I'm required to use the oTree library, which heavily builds on django. A solution that deviates from oTree as little as possible is desirable.

The `RadioSelectHorizontal` widget seems like the obvious choice here. But two differences to the default are mandatory:

1. the option labels ("agree", "neutral", etc.) have to be positioned just underneath the radio buttons.
2. the radio buttons have to be evenly spaced. (Ideally, they are aligned across the entire page)

In contrast, the default look will have the labels between the radio buttons and allow only as little space as each label needs:

---

[image]

---

The code:

```
question_1 = models.IntegerField(widget=widgets.RadioSelectHorizontal, 
                                 label="some question", 
                                 choices=[[1, "strongly disagree"], [2, "disagree"], [3, "neutral"], [4, "agree"], [5, "strongly agree"]])
```

How can I approach this?

django documentation mentions several approachs, i.e. custom widgets, custom CSS and more. But as far as I can tell, oTree is a bit more limited than django.

For illustration an example that meets both requirements:

---

[image]

Comment: What level of browser support is required? If it's reasonably new (like last 5 years or so) flexbox's justify-content:space-between is build to layout elements in exactly that fashion.

Comment: 5 years sounds reasonable, especially if this is a common standard. How is the browsers behavior if it's older? Will it result in an error or just look like the default?
And does this also help to put the labels underneath the radio buttons?

Comment: After a first look at a tutorial I'm not sure I can use this because I don't initiate each radio button manually. oTree (or django for that matter) intends you to create an `IntegerField` object which represents an entire question item.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a couple things before getting this right. This solution works for labels aligned above or below the button.

First, you need containers to place the question, the labels and the buttons. I am following the ideas laid out in this [reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145973/how-to-align-radio-buttons-horizontally-below-labels). In my case I needed every question inside a table, and every button inside a `td` for alignment purposes.

```
table.TheTable td.buttonGroup{
    width: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
}

div .labelWrap{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0.2em;
}

div .buttonWrap {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0.5em auto;
}
```

Once you have that, bear in mind that you have to place the `formfields` individually, and that you have to control for the label and the button **separately**.

```
<table>
  {{ for field in form }}
    <tr>                
      {{ for choice in field }}
      <td class="buttonGroup">
        <div class="buttonWrap"> {{ choice }} </div>
        <div class="labelWrap"> {{ choice.label }} </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{ endfor }}
</table>
```

Of course you will need to align and format other things. But I have laid out how to align the labels to the buttons only.